# The meaning of 殺しても殺したりねぇ

Tags: translation, particle-も, compound-verbs

I found this in a video game. It says 「殺しても【ころしても】殺したりねぇ【ころしたりねぇ】」. So, my rough estimate was "Even killing (you) won't kill you". Is this correct? Also, what type of sentence is this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> 殺しても殺したりねぇ

殺したりねぇ is a collapsed, rough, usually masculine way of pronouncing 殺し[足]{た}りない, literally "don't kill enough". You use ～たりない like this:

> 食べたりない don't/didn't eat enough (-> I'm not full. I can / want to eat some more)
>   飲みたりない don't/didn't drink enough (-> I can / want to drink some more)
>   言いたりない don't/didn't say enough (-> I have more to say)

So I think 殺しても殺したりない is like "Even if I killed (you/someone) it wouldn't be enough / I would want to kill (you/someone) more," or "I wouldn't be satisfied even if I killed (you/someone)."

As pointed out by @broccoli forest, you could also read it as 「どれだけ殺しても殺したりない」, "No matter how many (people?) I kill, it won't be enough / I won't be satisfied / I will want to kill more."

Comment: お二人とも目的語を you にしているのでちょっと不安になったのですが、「どれだけ殺しても」という解釈にはならないんでしょうか。

Comment: あなるほどね・・そうとも読める～

Answer (score 5):

殺しても殺したりねえ literally means "I cannot kill you more - I'm not fully satisfied with even I killed you. But I was almost reading it as "殺しても、殺したりしねえ - I (can) kill you, but I won't kill you."

The writing , "殺しても殺したりねえ"　is verｙ confusing, like　"金おくれ (送れ) - Send me money" can be sometime mistaken for "金を呉れ - Give me money."

It's better to write "たり" in Kanji, i.e.,"殺しても殺し足りねえ," so that you may not confuse readers.